# Anti-Cryptolocker with "File Server Resource Manager"

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I use on Windows Server the feature "File Server Resource Manager" to create an anti-crypto bait file.

1) I create an "All Files" Group on "File Groups".
2) I create a "File Screen Templates"
3) I create a "File Screen", so every time a file will be created in the folder that I indicated previously, through a script all the Shared will be blocked.

You think that I can create a method so that the Share on the server are blocked not when a file is created in the folder but when the file that I indicate is modified?

Thank you

Comment: You assume the crypto-attack will come via sharing, not via infecting your server. This is a pretty limited case.

Comment: Yes, because the last time, a Computer on our Network had the crypto, and started to attack the Shared of the other Computers/Servers

Answer (score 0):

A layered approach is the best policy to deal with security threats. Using file screen can be useful but by its self, it would no be very effective.

1. **Limit share access** by configuring ACLs that prevents users from writing to files that they only need read-only access to. For a share where everyone needs access to create files, a good approach is to use the Creator-Owner user to assign full access permissions automatically. For all other users, assign read-only access.
2. **Configure previous versions** on the server to allow for a quick recovery if files get infected.
3. **Backup your server** using software that provides versioning. You want to make sure that your backups are 'offline' to prevent the malware from infecting the backups. Plus, don't go cheap - have a budget that allows several months to years of versions.
4. **Configure client security** I am not a big fan of antivirus because in my experience, it causes more problems than good. A better solution is to use something like Applocker to prevent unauthorized software from running on your client machines in the first place. With Applocker, only programs that are whitelisted are allowed to run and all others are blocked.
5. **Test your backups** and make sure they are working! you don't want to find out your backups are not working when you need them.